# How will Caliburn.Micro deal with being able to set breakpoints in Silverlight 5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, expression-blend, caliburn.micro, silverlight-5.0

We've been using MVVMLight for a while now, and we were looking into switching to using Caliburn.Micro.  While we were looking, our Design guy complained because blend doesn't do a good job at Dependency Injection.

Further thoughts on this made me wonder.  Caliburn.Micro doesn't use bindings at all, and Silverlight 5 allows for breakpoints on bindings.  Is that something that we would just not get using Caliburn.Micro?  What are the thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C.M uses bindings but creates them on the fly according to the control Name and ViewModel's properties (convention over configuration). If you want to debug bindings, you will have to set them manually (which is also supported by C.M - it will not override your bindings).